# undefined method 'push' for string

Tags: arrays, ruby, methods

I'm working on a project to replicate Go Fish so I can learn more about structuring data and how to properly use arrays. I'm having a bit of trouble trying to figure out why I keep getting this error. I tried changing the variables into instance variable, this didn't seem to help much. I was hoping someone could take a peek at my code and point me in the right direction.
**Please feel free to give any suggestions, even if it's unrelated to the question. I don't know if I'm approaching this correctly.

```
card_deck = ["ace of spades", "ace of diamonds", "ace of clubs", "ace of hearts",
"two of spades", "two of diamonds", "two of hearts", "two of clubs",
"three of spades", "three of diamonds", "three of hearts", "three of clubs",
"four of spades", "four of diamonds", "four of hearts", "four of clubs",
"five of spades", "five of diamonds", "four of hearts", "five of clubs",
"six of spades", "six of diamonds", "six of hearts", "six of clubs",
"seven of spades", "seven of diamonds", "seven of hearts", "seven of clubs",
"eight of spades", "eight of diamonds", "eight of hearts", "eight of clubs",
"nine of spades", "nine of diamonds", "nine of hearts", "nine of clubs",
"ten of spades", "ten of diamonds", "ten of hearts", "ten of clubs",
"jack of spades", "jack of diamonds", "jack of hearts", "jack of clubs",
"queen of spades", "queen of diamonds", "queen of hearts", "queen of clubs",
"king of spades", "king of diamonds", "king of hearts", "king of clubs"]

puts "There are #{card_deck.length} cards in this deck."
puts "Welcome to Go-Fish."
print "Your name please: "
player_name = $stdin.gets.chomp.capitalize

puts "Ok #{player_name}, lets get this deck shuffled..."
#sleep(1)
# shuffles card_deck using .shuffle method
card_deck = card_deck.shuffle
puts "Cards are perfectly shuffled!"
#sleep(1)
puts "Dealing cards..."
#sleep(1)
# assigns first 7 cards to user
@my_hand = Array.new
@my_hand = card_deck[0..6].join(', ')
# assigns next 7 cards to CPU
@cpu_hand = Array.new
@cpu_hand = card_deck[7..13]

# removes first 14 cards from the deck (0-13)
@card_deck = card_deck.drop(13)

puts "Here's your hand: #{@my_hand}."
puts "You go first!"
puts "Do you have a..."
puts @cpu_hand.join(', ')
print "> "
@card = $stdin.gets.chomp.downcase

# if cpu has the card requested give it to the player and add to their array

if @cpu_hand.include?(@card)
  @my_hand.push(@card)
else
puts "Go fish!"
end
```

Comment: `@my_hand = card_deck[0..6].join(', ')` turns `@my_hand` to a string

Comment: the .join method?

Comment: Ok, I got it to work but I have a follow up question if you don't mind. If I never declare "@my_hand = @myhand.join(', ')" , then I'll have to repeat the code every time I want to print the value. Is there a way around this? Should I just create a second variable such as "@my_hand_printed" so that I can avoid this problem down the road?

Comment: Define a method that does it.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I appreciate the help!

Comment: Alternatively you can create a class *Hand* that inherits from array, then override the `to_s` method to your custom implementation.

Comment: Whenever you report an exception has been raised in an SO question please give the complete error message and the line at which it occurred.

Comment: Thanks, I'll make sure to do so next time. If I remember right, the only part I left out was the object ID, I figured it wasn't important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

push method

```
a = [ "a", "b", "c" ]
a.push("d", "e", "f")
        #=> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
[1, 2, 3,].push(4).push(5)
        #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

join method

```
[ "a", "b", "c" ].join        #=> "abc"
[ "a", "b", "c" ].join("-")   #=> "a-b-c"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove first 7 cards from deck and place them in the players hand, you need to do this operation:

```
@my_hand = card_deck.shift(7)
```

After that you can give next 7 cards to CPU:

```
@cpu_hand = card_deck.shift(7)
```

There is no need to make `drop` after that.
Also, drop(13) will drop exactly 13 elements, not 14 (0-13).

Additionally, you may like shorter version of deck initialization:

```
cards = ['ace','one','two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten', 'jack', 'queen', 'king']
suits = ['spades', 'clubs', 'diamonds','hearts']
card_deck = cards.product(suits).collect{|x,y| "#{x} of #{y}"}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Pavel. I was also trying to wrap my head around how I should structure the deck and this helped tremendously!